# SQL Cache dependency issue

Tags: asp.net, .net

I was caching the results inside a `DataSet` using the `SqlCacheDependency` .

Called out a simple code in page load

```
string conn= WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NorthwindEntities"].ConnectionString; 
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn); 
string query = "SELECT EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName, City FROM dbo.Employees"; 
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con); 
SqlDataAdapter dadapter= new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
```

DataSet usage :

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 
dadapter.Fill(ds, "Employees");
```

And cached it as :

```
SqlCacheDependency empDependency = new SqlCacheDependency(cmd); 
Cache.Insert("Employees", ds, empDependency, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10),Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
```

However, I run the page,  data loads in grid view and then I modify manually from SQLServer itself. I reload the page and the changed data is immediately visible.

Which line is creating issue OR is anything missing ?

Answer (score 1):

Got the issue  here.

SqlDependency notification system wasn't up and running. This was resolved by correctly setting up the Global.asax file `Application_Start` method.

```
protected void Application_Start()
 {
    string connString =   
    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProductionSystem"].ConnectionString;
    SqlDependency.Start(connString); // starting the listener service 
}
```

This [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/andrewrea/archive/2008/07/13/sqlcachedependency-i-think-it-is-absolutely-brilliant.aspx) helped me.